# is there a way to make a google form response be formatted and sorted on a sheet with multiple pages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form that sends responses to a google sheet, I want to be able to populate different pages in the sheet depending on a selection from a drop-down menu in the form.

I would also like to format it differently than how the form automatically populates the sheet if this is possible

I have looked for some proper documentation on how to do this but it's hard to find for me, I have tried a sheets formula but this did not work and using google apps script is hard for me since I have no understanding of how it works properly.

```
=FILTER('Form Responses '!A2:Z,'Form Responses '!B2:B="topic")

=QUERY('Form Responses '!A2:Z,"where B='topic'")
```

this gives me the `no matches are found in filter evaluation` error

Comment: As far as the formatting goes it would probably be easier to create templates and then load the data from the Linked Sheet into the sheets via script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=query('Form Responses'!A2:H,"Select * Where B='topic'")
```

Adding this to the seperate pages fixed my problem with the filtering and using templates lets me keep the formatting i wanted, thanks cooper!

Comment: Accept your answer it its what you need so people in future can find the correct solution